# separate IP address for wildcard sub domain

Tags: java, apache, wildcard

My project is a template engine using wildcard sub domain for different users.
each subdomains are dynamiclly generated like user1.domain.com,user2.domain.com etc.contents are loaded dynamically.

It also use wildcard ssl for security.

is it possible to assign separate IP address for each sub domains?

My project is developed in java and struts.

Help is highly appreciable

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign any DNS records (including A or AAAA with IP addresses) to your domain names. SSL certificates check only if the domain name matches.

You can have `foo.example.com` pointing 1.1.1.1 and `bar.example.com` pointing to 2.2.2.2 and wildcard SSL certificate for `*.example.com` will work with it correctly.

Of course wildcard SSL certificate `*.example.com` will not work for `aaa.bbb.example.com` because only a single level of subdomain matching is supported, but that's nothing to do with IP addresses.

**Update:** I see now the question was about [wildcard DNS records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), not (only) about [wildcard SSL certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate). See comments. I will update this answer later.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response ,my subdomains are dynamically generated like user1.example.com,user2.examaple.com etc.is it possible   separate ip for each one of these subdomains?

Comment: I see you mean wildcard DNS record, not only wildcard SSL certificate... Well, you can have only one wildcard DNS record with one (or multiple) IP address. If you need different IP addresses for different "dynamically generated" DNS records then you cannot do only with wildcard DNS record. I see 2 options here: 1) create normal, not wildcard DNS records - it should be easy in cloud DNS services like Amazon AWS Route 53 2) maybe you don't really need it - use one IP address (and a wildcard DNS record) as a "front-end" to servers with other IP addresses.